# FFMPEG Concat Videos with audio on some and not others

Tags: c#, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am rendering video from a camcorder with its perspective audio.  I am then concatenating several of the rendered video files together to make one video file.  The problem I am having is that some videos will need audio and some will not, depending on the user's preference.  If all of the videos need audio or all of the videos do not need audio, all works well.  However, if audio is selected on some and not others, I have problems.  For example, if I have three videos that need to be concatenated, the first has audio, the second does not have audio and third does have audio, then the final rendered file plays the audio of the third video on the second video and no audio on the third.

Below is the parameters for rendering each video file with audio:

```
parameters = "-y -i " + frames[0].VideoPath + " -f lavfi -t " + frames[1].TimeCode.TotalSeconds + @" -i anullsrc -filter_complex " + '"' + "[0:v]trim=" + frames[0].TimeCode.TotalSeconds + ":" + frames[1].TimeCode.TotalSeconds +
            @", setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[trimedv0];[0:a]atrim=" + frames[0].TimeCode.TotalSeconds + ":" + frames[1].TimeCode.TotalSeconds + @", asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a];[trimedv0]yadif," + orientation + @"setsar=1/1, eq=contrast=1:brightness=0, drawtext=text=\'%{pts\:localtime\:" + ToUnixTimestamp(frames[0].FrameTime) +
            @"\:'" + CurrentDisplayDateFormat.DateOutputFormat + @"'}\'" + @":fontfile=\'Fonts/" + font.FirstOrDefault() + @"\':fontcolor=" + fontColor + ":x=" + DATEXOFF +
            ":y=" + DATEYOFF + " -th:fontsize=" + tempFont +
            @":box=1:boxcolor=" + boxColor + @"@" + opacity + @", drawtext=text=\'%{pts\:localtime\:" + ToUnixTimestamp(frames[0].FrameTime) + @"\:'" + CurrentDisplayDateFormat.TimeOutputFormat + @"'}\'" + @":fontfile=\'Fonts/" + font.FirstOrDefault() + @"\':fontcolor=" + fontColor +
            ":x=" + TIMEXOFF + ":y=" + TIMEYOFF +
            " -th:fontsize=" + tempFont + @":box=1:boxcolor=" + boxColor + @"@" + opacity + '"' + " -sn -map [a] -shortest -ac 2 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mpegts -c:a aac " +
            vidPath + @"\v" + outputFile.ToString() + ".TMP";
```

Below is the parameters without audio:

```
parameters = "-y -i " + frames[0].VideoPath + " -filter_complex " + '"' + "[0:v] trim=" + frames[0].TimeCode.TotalSeconds + ":" + frames[1].TimeCode.TotalSeconds +
            @", setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[trimedv0];[trimedv0]yadif," + orientation + @"setsar=1/1, eq=contrast=1:brightness=0, drawtext=text=\'%{pts\:localtime\:" + ToUnixTimestamp(frames[0].FrameTime) +
           @"\:'" + CurrentDisplayDateFormat.DateOutputFormat + @"'}\'" + @":fontfile =\'Fonts/" + font.FirstOrDefault() + @"\':fontcolor=" + fontColor + ":x=" + DATEXOFF +
            ":y=" + DATEYOFF + " -th:fontsize=" + tempFont +
            @":box=1:boxcolor=" + boxColor + @"@" + opacity + @", drawtext=text=\'%{pts\:localtime\:" + ToUnixTimestamp(frames[0].FrameTime) + @"\:'" + CurrentDisplayDateFormat.TimeOutputFormat + @"'}\'" + @":fontfile =\'Fonts/" + font.FirstOrDefault() + @"\':fontcolor=" + fontColor +
            ":x=" + TIMEXOFF + ":y=" + TIMEYOFF +
            " -th:fontsize=" + tempFont + @":box=1:boxcolor=" + boxColor + @"@" + opacity + '"' + " -sn -an -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 " +
            @"-pix_fmt yuv420p -f mpegts " + vidPath + @"\v" + outputFile.ToString() + ".TMP";
```

Below is the parameters to concatenate the video files to one file:

```
string parameters = "-probesize 100M -analyzeduration 100M -i concat:" + '"' + concatString + '"' + @" -c:v copy " + ExportOptions.CompleteDestinationPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I put the following in the filter_complex and all works well:

```
[0:a]volume=enable=between(t,(BeginMuteTime),(EndMuteTime)):volume=0, asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a];
```